# What firewall ports need to be open for Active Directory?

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, active-directory, windows-firewall

I want to run DFS replication between a couple of servers. It's my understanding that the servers need to be part of a domain for this. Being able to give people a username and password that works on all servers would be useful too, so I can lock up the admin password.

All machines will be running Windows 2008R2 and they will all be running Windows Firewall, so I need to be able to allow the other machines to connect to this server, but lock out everyone else.

So my question is: what ports do I need to allow the machines to connect to the Domain Controller over?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this [blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/rexiology/archive/2006/04/05/89389.aspx) from an MVP.

- TCP 135 : MS-RPC
- TCP 1025 & 1026 : AD Login & replication
- TCP 389 : LDAP
- TCP & UDP 53 : DNS
- TCP 445 : SMB , Microsoft-ds
- TCP 139 : SMB
- UDP 137 & 138 : NetBIOS related
- UDP 88 : Kerberos v5

Comment: I would contest the 1025 and 1026 - they were probably used as ephemeral ports in that poster's testing, but that's not a relevant listening service.  And you'll want TCP/88 for Kerberos as well.